# XCode 4 stops printing to Debug Area after a few dozen lines

Tags: xcode, xcode4, printf, cout

I am just after upgrading to XCode 4.

I am developed a simple game engine on OSX and iOS using C/C++ (with some Objective C for setting up window). I am using OpenGL for graphical programming and I have a interface made in Interface Builder sitting around the NSOpenGL view window.  For my testing of different pieces of functionality I rely heavily on being able to print with `cout << or printf(..)`.

My project worked fine in XCode 3. But in XCode 4 after a few dozen lines the debug area's output stops printing out from my program. Has anyone else experienced this problem and been able to fix it?

It is realy causing problems for me in development, and I am considering purchasing a new mac in he next 6 months so I need to use XCode 4 for this project.

Comment: If you use NSLog() instead of cout/printf(), do you have the same issue?

Comment: Yeah, I tried usng NSLog() and the same thing was happening.

I appear to have solved the problem. I have removed all the printf() and cout statements when I initialise my program and now only print out in the program's main loop. This appears to have solved it.

I can only assume that in my Initialization I was printing some sort of character sequence that XCode 4 doesn't like. Unfortunately I don't have time at the minute to go through all my code and find out exactly what was causing the problem. 

If I fall across exactly wat was causing the problem in the future I will come back and post

Comment: I am experiencing the same problems as you described. I'm printing cout while iterating over an array (cout << ... << endl , so it **should** flush the stream), and output stops after 16 lines - even though the loop continues to run. Running the program through terminal outputs all character correctly

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try switching to a different debugger and then back again to the one you want? Maybe a full shut down in between.